# Unable to start Stopped (Deallocated) Virtual Machine

Tags: azure, virtual-machine

A couple of months ago our MSDN Visual Studio subscription was appeared cancelled. When contacted Microsoft, they restored our account. But all our servers running in the subscription was stopped. But I was able to start all servers except one (Ubuntu server). It was showing "internal server error". We managed to recover most of the data from our backups. But I would like to recover some other data that was not in the backup. Now, when I tried starting the server, it shows the error "A disk with nae xxxxxx-2012080707000 does not exist in the subscription". When checked, this particular disk is not listed in the "Disks" tab in Virtual Machines.

I am unable to attach or detach disks to the VM or upgrade it.
How can i troubleshoot it and start the VM
Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

Since the VHDs are stored as page blobs in blob storage, you can start by looking for a page blob named the same as your disk. Usually you would find these blobs in `vhds` blob container. If you have this blob, you can create a disk using this and attach it to your VM. However if the blob is not there, then I don't think you can do anything.